# Wordpress variable, user created, woocommerce product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Basically I am interested in using woocommerce to sell a product . This product is a Print Order of a external printing service that I have implemented in a brand new plugin.

What I want now is after the order, is to be able to put that "order" in the buy cart, and buy it normally as just another woocommerce product.

The product has to be created on the fly, manually by a way of some function that I can use to create a product during a certain workflow point.

Can you help me to find a solution?
Using woocommerce or not!

Comment: I did something similar in woocommerce. here's my concept. Put the products as posts, setup generic product with dimensions as variations for pricing. upon buy now, have the product image applied to the generic product (only needs to be displayed to the visitor), manage visitor interactions using sessions. hope that made sense :)

Comment: First of all, thanks! OKkkkkkkkk, so you basicaly stored the info of each order in a post. That was my thought to but basically i need also to store the product after they are displayed to the person, and also need to secure the payment, like a normal product. The price may not be a fixed variation. . . it can spam a wide range of prices. impossible to fiz them. So this way i would need a way to create a product, when the user is chosing the various options, on our WP site.

Comment: Think of your product as a glass and the posts as beverages, let the visitor decide the beverage and you put that in the glass ;)

Comment: You can customize a stock item and save the custom purchased version as order item meta. See [`wc_add_order_item_meta()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_add_order_item_meta.html)

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your requirement/comments is that you want to be able to dynamically create a product, which is bad idea. But here is my suggestion.

**Lets say you have a simple product called "Print Job" with a price of $1 and with an id of 10. And i am supposing that your external printing service would send back a response with the order and the price of printing, lets say $64.**

Once you recieve the response you can simply call **add_product_to_cart(10)**, this will automatically add the print job product to your cart.

```
/************* functions.php ***************/
function add_product_to_cart($product_id) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add this function in your functions.php, **this function will override the price of the product i.e "Print Job" with the actual price of $64.**

```
/******************* Functions.php ****************/
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'override_printing_price' );

function override_printing_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 64;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies ! BTW, why is it a bad idea to dinamicaly create a product? Because if i dont create a dinamic product how can a charge for the order? Is there another way. I am a software developer, but i am time pressed to find a solution quickly. Non the less, i allllllllllllways prefer to do things "The right Way!" . . . . Do telll....

Comment: In programming always think about the benefits you get from a certain approach.
Lets assuming that you will delete the product once its been created and ordered. If you delete all the records of the product then whats the point in creating them in the first place, when you can just override the price of another product. 
On the other hand if you do intend to keep the products, then soon there will be tons of products in woocommerce that you wont use anymore and will eventually slow down your website. 
So at the end of the day you dont get any plus point from this approach, nor is it efficient.